# Snowflake REGEX to get last 7-digit number in a string

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write a regex in Snowflake that will return the last 7-digit number from a string. Non-working example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('4000400 - Widget Revenue:4000401 - Special Widgets:4000422 - Tiny Special Widgets', '\D*\d+\D+(\d+).*')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `'(\\d{7})(\\D*)$'` and accessing first subgroup:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('4000400 - Widget Revenue:4000401 - Special Widgets:4000422 - Tiny Special Widgets'
     ,'(\\d{7})(\\D*)$',1,1,'e',1) AS result
```

Output:

```
4000422
```

---

EDIT:

Handling numbers that are shorter than 7 digits after last occurence of 7 digits number:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('6000700 - Benefit Expense:6000820 - Benefits - 401k Match'
                     ,'(\\d{7})(\\D+\\d{0,6}\\D*)*$',1,1,'e',1);
-- 6000820


SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('4000400 - Widget Revenue:4000401 - Special Widgets:4000422 - Tiny Special Widgets'
                    ,'(\\d{7})(\\D+\\d{0,6}\\D*)*$',1,1,'e',1);  
-- 4000422
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the 'e' doing there?

Comment: @influent `e` stands for extract submatches. It seems it could be skipped: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html

Comment: This example returns NULL and I can't figure out why. 
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('6000700 - Benefit Expense:6000820 - Benefits - 401k Match','(\\d{7})(\\D*)$',1,1,'e',1)
I also don't understand how your code knows to grab the last number group and not the first.

Comment: Looks like it's because it's finding a number after the last 7-digit group but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: @influent "I also don't understand how your code knows to grab the last number group and not the first." - it is becasue of $, it means the substring has to start with 7 digit number and be ended with any number of non digit characters. I have exteded it to handle occurences of shorter number(here 401) afterwars